# Find Value in File Contents

Tags: python, file, recursion, search

I have a list of values in a file. I'm trying to read in that file and see if those values exist in a folder. If they don't exist, I just want a line that says it doesn't exist so that I can put it into a csv and work on the missing files.

I'm doing this with Python.

So far, I've been able to get it to read the files, but it's not writing the output to a file like I want it to.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import os
import re 
# Get the list of files in the directory
files = os.listdir("W:\JA\JA's Coding Curiosity\Python\Test Folder\Test Files")

# Create a list of values to check for
with open("W:\JA\JA's Coding Curiosity\Python\Test Folder\Values.txt", 'r') as f:
    my_list = f.readlines()

list_without_newline = [line.strip() for line in my_list]

# Check if each value exists in any of the files
for value in list_without_newline:
    if any(value in file for file  in files):
        with open("W:\JA\JA's Coding Curiosity\Python\Test Folder\Results.txt",'w') as f:
            f.write("is\\T{}\\T{}\n".format(value, files[files.index(value)]))
    else:
        with open("W:\JA\JA's Coding Curiosity\Python\Test Folder\Results.txt",'w') as f:
            f.write("not\\T{}\\T{}\n".format(value, files[files.index(value)]))
```

This is what I get back

```
PS W:\JA\JA's Coding Curiosity\Python\Test Folder> python FileSearch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\JA\JA's Coding Curiosity\Python\Test Folder\FileSearch.py", line 19, in <module>
    f.write("not\\T{}\\T{}\n".format(value, files[files.index(value)]))
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: '12919031' is not in list
```

I also tried moving the folder to my C drive but then nothing happens at all.

Comment: `files` and `value` are the issue. `files` is a list of paths and `value` is a string from `my_list`. They presumably don't overlap and in that case your `else` `write()` happens and you hit that error on `files[files.index(value)])`

Comment: Why is this tagged `recursion`? There are no functions in your code, let alone recursive ones.

Comment: `any(value in file for file  in files)` looks for filenames that have `value` as a substring. But `files.index(value)` looks for a complete match, not a substring.

Comment: The `else` block is executed when `value` isn't found in `files`. So why would you expect to be able to use its index?